# Filtering Ruby array of hashes by another hash

Tags: ruby

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.  It seems tricky to filter a hash by another hash or multiple key/value pairs.

```
fruit = [
  { name: "apple",   color: "red",    pieable: true  },
  { name: "orange",  color: "orange", pieable: false },
  { name: "grape",   color: "purple", pieable: false },
  { name: "cherry",  color: "red",    pieable: true  },
  { name: "banana",  color: "yellow", pieable: true  },
  { name: "tomato",  color: "red",    pieable: false }
]
filter = { color: "red", pieable: true }

# some awesome one-liner? would return
[
  { name: "apple",   color: "red",    pieable: true  },
  { name: "cherry",  color: "red",    pieable: true  }
]
```

The array of hashes I don't think is the problem.  I don't even know how to test a hash by another arbitrary hash.  I'm using Rails so anything out of active_support etc is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COULD be made into a one liner. But multi-line is cleaner.

```
fruit.select do |hash| # or use select!
  filter.all? do |key, value|
    value == hash[key]
  end
end
```

Comment: Multi-line is completely fine.  Man, I took at least five whacks at this.  This is exactly what I was trying to do.  Brilliant --> .all? never used that.  `3 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips`  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you allow two lines it could also be made into an efficient "one-liner" like so:

```
keys, values = filter.to_a.transpose 
fruit.select { |f| f.values_at(*keys) == values }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient (you could just use an array form of `filter` to avoid repeated conversions), but:

```
fruit.select {|f| (filter.to_a - f.to_a).empty? }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to use [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for this:

```
fruit.group_by { |g| { color: g[:color], pieable: g[:pieable] } }[filter]
  #=> [{:name=>"apple",  :color=>"red", :pieable=>true},
  #    {:name=>"cherry", :color=>"red", :pieable=>true}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tony Arcieri (@bascule) gave this really nice solution on twitter.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'  # unneeded if you are in a rails app
fruit.select { |hash| hash.slice(*filter.keys) == filter }
```

And it works.

```
# [{:name=>"apple", :color=>"red", :pieable=>true},
# {:name=>"cherry", :color=>"red", :pieable=>true}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fruit.select{ |hash| (filter.to_a & hash.to_a) == filter.to_a }

=> [{:name=>"apple", :color=>"red", :pieable=>true}, 
    {:name=>"cherry", :color=>"red", :pieable=>true}]
```